# Can I read parts of file and store in a property?

Tags: ant

I want to include the first say 50 lines from a changes.txt file as the body of an automated release mail.

Is there a simple way to do this? Preferably without rolling my own Task or using JavaScript etc.

I managed to do it using `exec` and `arg`s 'head' and '-50' but that won't work for Windows/Cygwin guys on the team. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an example in the [Ant manual](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html), though not perhaps easy to find in the filterchains page ...

```
<loadfile srcfile="changes.txt" property="changes">
  <filterchain>
    <headfilter lines="50"/>
  </filterchain>
</loadfile>
```

There's also the `skip` attribute that can be used to skip over a number of lines, so this would take lines 11-60:

```
<headfilter lines="50" skip="10" />
```